# Where to find strategies to define network topologies for complex websites?

Tags: networking, web-server, web-hosting

All that I found is tutorials that assume that the whole website is hosted in the same server. All the database, the file server, the web server, the mail server - all in the same machine.

I'm interested in learning from books or video format some efficient strategies to make a scalable growing website.

Best to all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for or not but I always find this site a handy read on the topic:

http://highscalability.com/

FYI - I have nothing to do w/that site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tremendous generalisation but most decent-sized organisations split their servers into at least three tiers - web servers in a DMZ, apps servers behind them then databases behind further still. Each layer is separated by firewalls and there's an option for another layer behind all three of these for secure systems. No two layers make use of any common devices (except said firewalls of course). This is organisationally very clear and is certainly pretty secure, better still as a model it works on just about every major website you'll ever visit.

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest to start with:**

- Cal Henderson's [Building Scalable Web Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596102356).
- Theo Schlossnagle's [Scalable Internet Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232699X).
- And then reading the case stories at http://highscalability.com/.